# ESB with DSS feature, how to use boxcarring?

Tags: esb, pass-through

I've installed the DSS 3.2.2 feature on ESB 4.8.1, and I can't use boxcarring, the session cookie cannot created after send begin_boxcar. I tried to change passthrough transport to nhttp, but no success.

Is possible to use DSS feature with ESB instance? There some configuration tha I can make to fix this?